# Linking errors for pugixml in wchar mode

Tags: c++, xml, pugixml

When I'm trying to build a binary using pugi in wchar mode, I get a load of linker undefined reference errors hinting at the lack of `wchar_t` versions of some functions in the library.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and `libpugixml-dev` that I got from apt-get.

Here's an example code that refuses to build:

```
#include <pugixml.hpp>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pugi::xml_node n;
    n.set_name(L"");

    return 0;
}
```

I build with

```
g++ -o pugi_test main.cpp -std=c++11 -DPUGIXML_WCHAR_MODE -lpugixml
```

and get

```
undefined reference to `pugi::xml_node::set_name(wchar_t const*)'
```

I also tried putting `#define PUGIXML_WCHAR_MODE` in `main.cpp` above `#include`, and uncommenting the same `#define` in `pugiconfig.hpp`.

If I remove all traces of wchar (`L""` ⇒ `""` and remove `-DPUGIXML_WCHAR_MODE`), build goes without a hitch.

Am I supposed to rebuild the library if I want to use wchar mode? I couldn't find anything of relevance in [the manual.](https://pugixml.org/docs/manual.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Am I supposed to rebuild the library if I want to use wchar mode?

Yes. It would make little sense to have such `PUGIXML_WCHAR_MODE` macro unless it controlled the compilation of the library (in my opinion). It must be (un-)defined both when compiling the library and the user of the library.